# row counts counts off by more than one thousand and size of file confirms

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

EDIT - add - this warning from myphpadmin despite only having now 300 some odd rows visible.

[image]

This was previously closed but the answer does not address how the table can be more than 1000 rows off, nor does it address the kb size shown. The answer this claimed as a dup for says that it can be SLIGHTLY off since its an estimate. I would not call 1000+ rows slightly and therefore this is not answered by the supposed duplicated question

Can someone help me understand why the reported row count does not match the auto incrementing id's that are my primary key? Before re-inserting the data that is in there now, I emptied the table using myphpadmin empty function
[image: empty function]

After emptying I reinserted and it shows 1202 rows in the table. [image: 1202 rows]

But when I browse the table, it shows only 159 records. Why and where are the other records?

Here is some extra inforomatio abotu the row counts and hwo they operate withint he context of the database itself

[image]

Comment: 'The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the exact count' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html What do you get when you query (ie not relying on phpmyadmins spin on things)

Comment: And please add result of show create table <tablename>

Comment: @p.salmon thank you. It is a MYISAM db. When I run a query it shows the 159 records. What confused me most is that those records dont take up almost .50mb.Is myphpadmin just wrong? I am not sure what query you are looking for with "

And please add result of show create table <tablename>"

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html - I want to see what auto_increment is set to you could also SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,`AUTO_INCREMENT`,TABLE_ROWS  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourtablename' this will also show how many rows the information_schema thinks the table has

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? How many columns are in your table? IIRC, there was a bug about this that was fixed some time ago, but having a large number of columns is going to be a potential problem as much as a large number of rows shown on your results page would be (note that this is about the number of rows *shown*, not the total stored in your database, of which phpMyAdmin can deal easily with).

Comment: @isaacbennetch thanks. its 4.9.7. There were only about 210 columns that I could see.

Comment: @p.salmon thanks. A.I. was up to about 210 which is why I was so confused.